# Compile typescript file from t4 template

Tags: t4, typescript, envdte, web-essentials

I have created a t4 template which creates typescript dto files based on my c# dtos. During the generation I also want to compile the produced ts files into js files and add them to the solution, just like web essentials does for me when I save a ts file.

My initial thought was to somehow trigger the save event;

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE) ((IServiceProvider) this.Host).GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
dte.OpenFile(EnvDTE.Constants.vsViewKindAny, outputFilePath);
```

Save the file (to trigger the compile) and then close it again. But I can not get this to work.

Does anyone have an idea for me?

Comment: Seems like it'd be way easier to just invoke tsc.exe directly?

Comment: You might be right, still it would be interesting to know if it is doable.

Comment: @Julius: Can you explain how you did?

Comment: See my own answer bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing as proposed by Ryan Cavanaugh and just invoking the compiler. I used [Olegs tips for creating more than one output for a template](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template) to add the generated files to the project and tt template.

I kicked off the compiler by the following code:

```
<#+ 
void CompileTypeScriptFile(string fullFileName)
{
    var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "tsc.exe",
            Arguments = "--target ES5 \"" + fullFileName + "\""

        }
    };
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do that is to have a separate Build Target (or Task) that runs after the T4 template and compiles the output. T4 does not seem the right fit for this.

Comment: Could you elaborate with an example of how to do this? Do not want to recompile all ts files in the project (it takes to looooong)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [T4Toolbox](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7f9bd62f-2505-4aa4-9378-ee7830371684) to associate your T4 file with the .ts files. It adds "Custom Tool Template" to the Visual Studio Properties Window and provides a custom tool called T4Toolbox.TemplatedFileGenerator that will transform the template automatically whenever the .ts file is saved. You can use the [output management](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/03/t4-tutorial-integrating-generated-files-in-visual-studio-projects/) functionality of the T4Toolbox to add the generated .js file to the desired place in the solution.